# androidでxls形式のデータを印刷したい

Tags: java, android, excel

androidでxls形式のデータを印刷できるようなアプリを自作したいと思っているのですが、中々上手く行きません。

印刷はとりあえずxlsファイルをgoogleクラウドプリントに送りたいのですがエラーが出ます。
アドバイスいただけますか。

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {

        InputStream f = this.getAssets().open("seisansyo.xls"); // 既存のExcelファイル名を指定
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(f);
        f.close(); //ここで入力ストリームを閉じる
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/date/" + "workbook2.xls");
        // 編集したいシート、列、セルを指定
        Sheet s =wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row r = s.getRow(1);
        Cell c = r.getCell(1);
        // この場合B2セルに「あいう」をセット
        c.setCellValue("あいう");
        c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/date/" + "workbook2.xls");
        String mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType(mimeType);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, file.getName());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getPath()));
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.cloudprint");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (IOException oops) {
        Log.e("error", oops.toString());
        oops.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: エラーが出ている箇所や、例外が出たときのスタックトレースがあると、原因が特定しやすくなるのではないかと存じます。

Comment: 他の形式のファイルは送られますか？

Comment: startActivity(intent);の部分でエラーが出ます。
他形式のファイルも送れません。